# Translate key events to nothing?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

My Macbook Pro has a touch bar which is causing me to make a bunch of hard-to-find errors

If my finger mistakenly hits the F3 through F12 positions on the touch bar, the front end inserts an invisible character (\.00) which is causing errors.

So, my solution would be to edit KeyEventTranslations.tr

and do something like what is already done for F1.
Item[KeyEvent["F1", Modifiers->{Shift}],SelectionHelpDialog[False]]

But, map it to what?  I'd like it to do *nothing*.  I can't find any documentation for KeyEvent.  Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: just remove (or comment out) the line that defines the key event Shift+F1?

Comment: It is keys 10,11, and 12 that I am hitting by accident, so I’d like to map those.