# Mac Touch Bar and Hidden Characters

Tags: front-end, keyboard, interface

I am reposting this question ([Translate key events to nothing?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191727/translate-key-events-to-nothing)) hoping to resolve an issue that is causing me no end of, bug chasing.  Arggh, Help.

On a Mac with a touchbar, if my finger slips and hits any of F2-F12, an invisible character .00 is entered.  It would be ok if I could see the character and find the error. But, I can't see it as it is, ummm, invisible. (I've been copying and pasting every input to a vi buffer to look for the .00)

Is there any way to make .00 show up as a visible character? Or better yet, map F2-12 to something other than entering a visible character?

I've tried adding to KeyEventsTranslations.tr:

```
Item[KeyEvent["F3"], SelectionHelpDialog[False]],
```

etc...

```
Item[KeyEvent["F12"], SelectionHelpDialog[False]]
```

Comment: Addendum; Dynamic[ControllerState[]] indicates that the touch bar keys are call Touch Button N, where N \in Range[1,11].   I am not sure if this helps.

Comment: What do the cell contents (Cell | Show Expression) of an affected cell look like?

Comment: @CarlWoll `Cell[BoxData["\.00"], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.7656654818730288`*^9}]`

Comment: Can't you just replace \.00 with nothing in the Find dialog?

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Yes, that’s it. The “.\00” doesn’t appear in the front end. (Silly of me nor to do the shift control e to look, palm slap)

Comment: @Carl Woll, that is a possible solution. The problem is that I don’t always know that there is a missing character—and the error propagates. So, I would need to do the find-replace periodically, which I suppose I could do with a scheduled task, but...

Comment: I’m a bit surprised that no one else is reporting this. I can’t be the only incompetent typist in the world.

Comment: In M11.3- you could do `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {{"KeyDown", "\.10"} :> Beep[]}]`. I don't know how to get something similar to work in M12.

Comment: Thanks @Carl Woll. I’ll try that tomorrow in M12. I wouldn’t have arrived at that solution. I’ll report back.

Comment: @Carl Woll, Sigh. That didn't work in M11.3 or M12.  Interesting that ControllerState does't show the touch bar buttons in M12, but does in M11.3

Answer (score 1):

1) This is a preexisting bug. It's slightly worse in V12 because it's inserting a null byte rather than a control character, and that null byte doesn't seem interceptable.

2) This isn't specific to the touch bar.  The same thing happens with an external keyboard.

3) I presume you're noticing this because, like me, you have the touchbar set to show function keys by default.  But that's a very non-default configuration.  Whereas hitting F1 is pretty easy to do a normal keyboard. So now it's the set of sloppy typists who have touchbars configured to produce function keys, which is perhaps why others haven't commented on this.

4) Possible workarounds for now are to configure the touchbar not to show functions keys and/or get in the habit of using Shfit-Cmd-F instead of F1 to avoid the danger zone.

Comment: It's good to note that the touch bar can be configured on a per-app basis. If OP prefers function keys by default, they can still be turned off for Mathematica only.

Comment: @Szabolcs and Itai.  Thanks.  I've tried all of the touch bar options and I can't the function keys to *not* show up with M11/M12 is running.  The problem for me is that my fingers slide off the top row of keys too often.  I appreciate your help.